# Why do I repeatedly get the same result with this unsynchronized code?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Consider this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Multithreading
{
    class Program
    {
        static int result = 0;

        static void changeResult1()
        {
            result = 1;
        }

        static void changeResult2()
        {
            result = 2;
        }

        static void changeResult3()
        {
            result = 3;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(changeResult1));
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(changeResult2));
            Thread t3 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(changeResult3));


            t1.Start();
            t2.Start();
            t3.Start();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that this code is NOT synchronized , meaning that `result` should be different each execution of the code (0,1,2,3) . From my point of view the result can even be `0` , if the Main thread is done before either one of the thread had even started .

However I'm repeatedly getting `2` as the result on screen .

Why ?

Comment: This is like race condition. Second thread is the last thread that assigns value to result

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Your MCV example doesn't convey an intention.

Comment: You'd probably benefit by using `Console.WriteLine` in addition to the assignments within the methods being used.

Comment: @StuartLC: I wanted to see what will happen without synchronization , I removed mutexes I placed earlier , however the same result (2) keeps repeating (I tested it under 100000 executions) .

Comment: While the thread running the Main method does `Console.WriteLine` the 3rd thread might not have gotten a chance to update `result` with 3. Now, this is only _one_ possibility. There are more. Number of cores/CPUs might also influence the outcome. Concerning "synchronization" first thing would be to state what you expect to happen, then the synchronization may be needed in places so that this can be achieved.

Comment: If it's of any help, I'm reproducing a comment I made to in the long discussion with @EricLippert: "I ran the code just a few times and got: 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, which is what I would expect from a race condition like this", i.e. that I expected to get different results, not this particular sequence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to me that the observed outcome is quite reasonable.

Starting threads is an expensive operation. I would expect that the start-up time of each of the threads to vastly outweigh the time taken to actually run the code assigned to each thread.

So once thread 1 is set-up, the main thread moves on to setting up thread 2 while thread 1 executes. Thread 1 finishes long before thread 2 is ready to run.

The same with thread 2 & thread 3.

So once thread three is set-up, thread 2 has well-and-truly finished, and the main thread moves immediately to the `Console.WriteLine(result);`. This is **before** thread 3 actually has begun, and is a long, long, long time after thread 2 has completed.

So, of course, the results is almost always `2`.

---

To support my unscientific analysis I thought I might add some timing code to see if I **could** be right.

```
void Main()
{
    times[0] = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(changeResult1));
    times[1] = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(changeResult2));
    times[2] = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(changeResult3));
    times[3] = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;

    t1.Start();
    times[4] = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
    t2.Start();
    times[5] = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
    t3.Start();
    times[6] = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
    var r = result.ToString();
    times[7] = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    times[8] = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    times
        .Select((x, n) => new { t = (x - times[0]).ToString("0.000"), n})
        .OrderBy(x => x.t)
        .Dump();
}

static Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
static double[] times = new double[15];

static int result = 0;

static void changeResult1()
{
    times[9] = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
    result = 1;
    times[10] = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
}

static void changeResult2()
{
    times[11] = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
    result = 2;
    times[12] = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
}

static void changeResult3()
{
    times[13] = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
    result = 3;
    times[14] = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
}
```

You have to follow the bouncing ball a little, but one such run of this code produced this output:

[image: results]

This is quite clearly showing that the code that executes after `t3.Start();` is the `var r = result.ToString();` and not the `result = 3;`. More importantly `result = 2;` has happened a long time before thread 3 has started.

Answer (score 9):

> Is this code correctly synchronized ?

No.

> meaning that result should be different each execution of the code (0,1,2,3) .

Why should that be true? You provide no justification whatsoever for this claim.

The code is incorrectly synchronized which means that there are many possible results. You are taking a fact -- **the lack of correct synchronization means I don't know what will happen** -- and deducing from that a completely unsupported conclusion -- **the observations will be different on every execution**.  The correct deduction from "I don't know what will happen" is that you don't know what will happen on *any* execution; in particular you do *not* know that the behaviour over a large set of runs will have *any* particular distribution.

> Why ?

Why what? You noted that 2 was a possible result, you are getting a possible result.  You do the same thing twice and the same result happens; that's not surprising. Just because the runtime is *permitted* to produce many different results does not imply that it *must* produce many different results. Doing the same thing twice generally results in pretty similar outcomes.

Comment: Actually I tested it around 100000 executions , got the same .

Comment: @ron: You still have not provided a justification for why you believe that you should get a different result. Tell you what, we'll play a game. You ask me to pick a number between one and ten. We'll play 100000 rounds. Am I allowed to pick 7 every time?  Would you be surprised if the result of every game was me picking 7?

Comment: This is partly a strawman. The OP's claim is not "I don't know what will happen", but "`result` should be different each execution". Obviously, when he sees he's getting the same result every time, he's confused. The fact that 2 is a possible solution does *not* explain **why** it's being the same solution every time.

Comment: thats correct. because `result = 2;` nearly takes no time to finish. also the last thread i guess the program ends before `result = 3;` executes because you dont wait. @ron

Comment: @ray: That you don't know what will happen is a consequence of the correct deduction that the program is incorrectly synchronized.

Comment: @ray: Now you're doing it. Why *shouldn't* the thread timings be the same every time the program is run? Just because the timings are not *documented* and just because they are *permitted* to be anything the runtime wants is not a *requirement* that the runtime somehow randomize the thread timings!

Comment: But from the premise of a program being incorrectly synchronized the deduction that a race condition is present and its behavior should be unpredictable can be made. Getting the same value back after 100K seems improbable enough to confuse some people.

Comment: Just put 
            `Task.Delay(1);` before console.WriteLine and you will see last thread gets a chance to do something! ;)

Comment: @ray: Who said anything about race conditions making programs *unpredictable*?  A race condition is not *required* to make a program nondeterministic. Why would anyone believe that it does?

Comment: @EricLippert: The burden of proof is on you to justify why the thread timings should be the same every time the program is run. I'm not going to fall for proving a negative when you're the one making the positive claim.

Comment: @ron: You said you wanted to see what would happen without synchronization. That implies that you did not know what would happen. And since you were surprised by what happened, that also implies that you did not know what would happen. Did you in fact know that 2 would be produced every time?

Comment: @ray: I'm not saying that they *should* be the same! I never said that. I'm saying that 2 is a permitted result and that it should not be surprising that every time the program is run, a permitted result is produced. The unsupported claim is the claim that it *must be different*. Plainly this claim -- which has yet to be justified in any way -- is false.

Comment: @EricLippert: "I'm saying that 2 is a permitted result and that it should not be surprising that every time the program is run, a permitted result is produced." You're missing the point. The OP is **not** wondering why a permitted result is produced. He is wondering **why is it the same every time?** Do you see the difference between what you're saying and what OP is actually asking?...

Comment: @ray: Right -- and my explanation is that the supposition that there is a requirement that running the same program twice produce a different value on every run is simply unsupported by any justification whatsoever. Why should it be surprising that running the same program twice produces the same results, when the runtime is permitted to do so?  You line up three runners and fire three starting pistols, a hundred thousand times. It seems reasonable that the same runner is going to win every race.

Comment: @EricLippert: It's not that it's "surprising", it's that the outcome is improbable. The thread scheduling algorithm may choose to schedule any given thread and the order in which the threads will be scheduled is not known in advance and can change. The OP is probably "surprised" at the fact that he got the same result every time. It's like asking for a random number and getting exactly the same value every time. Is it possible? Yes. Would you expect to get the same thing after 100K attempts? I'm pretty sure no one would. It might help if there's an internal .NET specific reason for it.

Comment: @ray: Now I am very confused. It's not surprising, but it is *improbable*? Leaving aside the question of whether an improbable event is inherently surprising, who said anything about *probability*? **The thread scheduler is not required to have probabalistic behaviour**. The algorithm *may* choose any thread, sure. It *does* choose a thread. **Why should anyone expect that it would do so at random**? Again, we are starting from a position of ignorance -- I don't know how the scheduler works -- and deducing from that "therefore it must be random" ?

Comment: @ray: Again, suppose we play a game where you ask me a number from 1 to 10. Do you *know* what numbers I'm going to say? No. Should you from that deduce that I am going to produce a uniformly distributed random sequence?  Absolutely not! It should be in no way surprising if I said 7 every time you asked, because obviously 7 is the best number.

Comment: @EricLippert: "Why should anyone expect that it would do so at random?" Why should anyone expect that a race condition would produce exactly the same outcome every time, acting as if it was indeed synchronized? I ran the code just a few times and got: 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, which is what I would expect from a race condition like this --in other words "unpredictable" from the PoV of an observer (not the implementation's). The comment about the scheduler being or not being probabilistic is irrelevant.

Comment: @EricLippert: Your game example is a false analogy. Unlike the thread scheduler, you have the *intention* of making the same choice every time before the game has begun only to try and prove a point --a self-fulfilling prophesy, if you will.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94473/discussion-between-eric-lippert-and-ray).

Comment: I think Eric is being nice and not using the term, but the point he is making I think is that this is a textbook argument from ignorance fallacy.